# Boost.best websocket ios.run() exits after sending a request and receiving one reply not receiving subsequent messages

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-beast

I am using boost beast websocket to subscribe to messages by sending a subscription message and should get back subscription reply and then the subscribed messages. The subscription reply is received but then ioc.run() returns and not receiving the additional messages. Please could you tell how to make it work?

Used example from boost beast without calling close.
 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp

```
// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    websocket::stream<
            beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::string host_;
    std::string text_;

public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
    session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
            : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
            , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc), ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
            char const* host,
            char const* port,
            char const* text)
    {
        // Save these for later
        host_ = host;
        text_ = text;

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
                host,
                port,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_resolve,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
            beast::error_code ec,
            tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
                results,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_connect,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(
                ssl::stream_base::client,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_ssl_handshake,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_ssl_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
                websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                        beast::role_type::client));

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::request_type& req)
                {
                    req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                            " websocket-client-async-ssl");
                }));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/ws",
                            beast::bind_front_handler(
                                    &session::on_handshake,
                                    shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        // Send the message
        ws_.async_write(
                net::buffer(text_),
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_write,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_write(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
                buffer_,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_read,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_read(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;

          }

    void
    on_close(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "close");
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto const host = "";
    auto const port = "";
     auto const text = "";

     net::io_context ioc;
     ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
     std::make_shared<session>(ioc, ctx)->run(host, port, text.c_str());
     ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Without reading all your code, understand that the run() method terminates if there is no pending work. For instance, your read method needs to queue up a new read.

Comment: cool, how do I queue up a new read?

Comment: Move `async_read()` to a separate function, let’s say `do_read()` and call it at the end of `on_read()`as well as where it currently is.

Comment: you mean this call: ws_.async_read(
                buffer_,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_read,
                        shared_from_this()));